# Webservices request does not meet wsp:policy expectations

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have some issues on validating my request against a server where implementation has been built with cxf 3.0.4.

The wsdl have following policy included:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyWSUID">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:SupportingTokens>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:UsernameToken
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:UsernameToken>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SupportingTokens>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

but when I try to run the request with following wss security section I got an error:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-AR32019390G5G595L002020395920395">
        <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

this is the error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}UsernameToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}WssUsernameToken10</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But when I try to run the same request against a server with another implementation (it is an IBM one) it works fine.
I read specification from here

http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf

and I didn't find any evidence of error from my request.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was not using PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.

Thanks to all anyway.